# How to see the DLQ messages in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I've configured the dead letter queue in logstash

Logasth.yml

```
 dead_letter_queue.enable: true
```

I didn't configure the path, so it uses the default path
`path.data/dead_letter_queue`

Test case:

```
input{
       // kafka

}

output{
    // elastic
}
```

I'm consuming payload from Kafka and writing into elastic search. I've sent a huge payload, by default elastic will index only 1000 fields. In this case it's giving 400 error.

```
"status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Limit of total fields [1000] has been exceeded"}}}}
```

Since it's a 400 message, it should go to the DLQ queue, right? But I'm not able to see the messages in that path `/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue`.

Did I miss anything in the DLQ config?

Comment: What do you see when running `du -h ./data` from your LOGSTASH_HOME folder?

Comment: I could see this output.  `4.0K ./data/queue` 
`4.0K ./data/dead_letter_queue
4.0K ./data/plugins/inputs/dead_letter_queue/main
8.0K ./data/plugins/inputs/dead_letter_queue
12K ./data/plugins/inputs
16K ./data/plugins
32K ./data`

Comment: So you have data in the DLQ. Now you need to use the [dlq input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/dead-letter-queues.html#processing-dlq-events) to process them